# What is the difference between "packing" and packaging"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, synonyms

I think this is a simple question, but it confuses me when I am creating sentences. I make a few searches on Google and find out that **the words are not synonymous**.

But in what context I will use "*packing*" and "*packaging*" in the correct way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll often see **P&P** as an additional costed item on commercial websites, but they don't always say what it stands for. I'm an eBay user, and I can assure you that they show *no consistency whatsoever* about whether it's **Post** or **Postage**, and **Packing** or **Packaging**.

Also note that Google Books claims 31K instances of [*post and packing*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22post%20and%20packing%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), and 17K [*post and packaging*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22post%20and%20packing%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22post%20and%20packaging%22&tbm=bks) (plus 125K/11K for ***postage*** and packing/packaging). They're all in common use, and it's inconceivable they mean different things.

So for that context, at least, I think it's fair to say *packing, packaging* are indeed synonyms. It's pointless trying to disambiguate by saying *packing* is the *process*, and *packaging* is the *material*. Most people are like eBay, and don't really make a distinction; some people would make precisely the *opposite* distinction.

---

For other contexts there are a wide range of distinctions. Software [*application packaging*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_packaging), for example, is never called *application packing*, and software [*packing alignment*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is never *packaging alignment*.

In short, the two words are sometimes synonyms, and sometimes not. Within the confines of an ELL answer it would be impossible to summarise all the different contexts where only one term is "correct". The best advice I could give is...

> *always use the simpler **packing** (whether it's as a gerund/noun, or a "continuous aspect" verb) unless **in your specific context** you've already noticed that most other people are using **packaging**.*

Answer (score 5):

Well in the way I am used to see it:

- [Packing](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/packing?s=t): From the verb **to pack**, Refers to the process of packing something up

> ```
> I am packing for my trip
> ```

- [Packaging](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/packaging): (noun) Refers to the package of the product

> ```
> I don't like the packaging of that product
> ```

Also, I don't think packaging is commonly used in informal contexts, you would mostly use "package".

But I have heard it when you are talking about a product in a commercial way. For example a team deciding on what is the best packaging for the product they are selling.

Also in software companies (or companies that produce software for internal use) they refer as **packaging** to the process that applications undergo so they can be used by the customers. For example they Create the Installation package and verify it can run in the different systems it is meant to be run.

**Update:**

About they not being synonyms as you mentioned. 
Maybe they are not marked as synonyms, but if you check at the definitions for the **Nouns** [packing](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/packing?s=t) and [packaging](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/packaging), you can see they basically mean the same, while it seems packaging might be a bit more "technical".

**So if:**

- You want a **Noun** to name the "package" itself you can use either **Packing** (definition 5) or **Packaging** (definition 2). 
  Although if you think your sentence could be ambiguous in the sense that people may read packing as a verb, you should use **packaging**.
- You want to refer to the **action** of creating the package, then use **Packing**.(Like I am packing ...) You can not say "I am packaging my cloths" since **packaging is not a verb.**
- You want to refer to the **act or instance of packing or forming packages**, like the First definition for Packaging says. You use Packaging, because It makes more relevant the idea of packaging as a process (like in software development).

Comment: *"packaging is not a verb."* - Yes it is. You gave an example of that yourself: the action of preparing software for distribution is called packaging. "Let me package that up for you" is something that you could say about a physical product. But it doesn't apply everywhere that *packing* does: you wouldn't say "I'm packaging my suitcase".

Answer (score 1):

+1 Good question.

The words are confusing especially in case of FMCGs. I'll try to answer my way and this could be applied in sentences you make.

Broadly, packaging and packing means something is wrapped or kept as it is in another thing. The **sole** purpose of this is to keep the main product safe, shock-proof and in some cases to attract the consumers (especially packing).

Now, let's see the subtlety -

Packaging is **generally** done by the factory owners as a **final process** where **packed** goods are further **packaged** into bigger boxes, cartons or whatsoever. On the other hand, **packing** is an augmented activity that adds value to the product inside (for instance, a sexy lady's arousing picture on a little wrapper of condoms).

Packing is something that's visible to the end users. Imagine you going to a supermarket and talking to your friend about the wonderful packing of a soap bar. Here, you cannot talk about the *packaging* because you haven't seen how those soap bars arrived in bulk in carton at the supermarket.

If you think microscopically, packaging would generally happen in a box whereas packing happens in anything. [Others opine that](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Difference_between_packaging_and_packing?#slide=1) *packing* is a verb and *packaging* is a noun - the material used in *packing*.

**Let's make things clear with pictures -**

*This is a typical example of packaging -*

[image: Typical example of packaging]

*This is a typical example of packing (though gift) -*

[image: Image for illustration only]

This gives us an idea (in case of goods)

> packing **generally** brings aesthetic value so that it **looks** good to the user/receiver/customer
>   packaging **generally** brings safety/security to avoid the damage to the product inside.

Soap's **packing** should be done with a wrapper (a thin, silky, shining paper) with a beautiful lady's picture on it. This will attract customers **but then** the **packaging** should be done using hard-box with product's name, batch number, address of manufacturers and other details (I'll least bothered about the lady's picture there!). This will make all the soaps inside safe and prevent damage when reach to the vendors.

**Also note** that when it comes to **travelling or moving**, the word *packing* is used more frequently over *packaging*. But this is made clear in this answer earlier that **packaging generally happens** in factories as the final process of making a (big?) parcel/box of **packed items**.

Comment: I agree with everything you've said here, except that in my understanding you have the terms backwards; "packaging" adds the aesthetic value and "packing" adds safety.

Comment: @Hellion: haha - I said in my own answer that if anybody were to propose a distinction between the two, someone else might make exactly the opposite distinction! In this case it's based on *aesthetics/functionality* rather than *process/material*, but the principle is the same. None of us really like "synonyms", so we look for some way to distinguish potential candidates. But it'll probably be a while yet before a consensus emerges.

Comment: @Hellion Well, there, I talked about the *noun* that people would understand. Yes, I did miss to mention it. When you look at a beautifully *packed* soap, the *packing* has an attractive lady on it.

Comment: That's exactly what I disagree with, @Maulik:  When I look at beautifully *packaged* soap, the *packaging* has an attractive lady on it.  And I expect to find 100 *packages* of soap *packed* inside a cardboard box.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Packing and Packaging** are two different terms that can use in a different place.

**Packing:** This Word refers to the term "The action to perform Something or Pack something."

let suppose before going to somewhere you usually pack your luggage This action refers to Packing.

While Packaging refers to other terms. Packaging is related to a product to pack them. It mainly Belongs to the thing in which we pack something. It may be paper or kraft material or Cardboard material.

Answer (score -2):

refer to google **packaging** is materials used to wrap or protect goods but **packing** means the action or process of packing something.
"all the ingredients and packaging are biodegradable"
"she finished her packing"